# Multiple assemblies using same DbContext - Changes not present in all assemblies

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My `DbContext` object is in it's own assembly, and I have to other assemblies that reference and use it.

For example:

- `Project.EF`

  This is the project that contains my EF context (`MyDbContext`) and models.
- `Project.API`

  This project references `Project.EF` and uses `MyDbContext` to perform updates.
- `Project.Service`

  This project also references `Project.EF` and uses `MyDbContext` to perform updates.

#### Problem:

When I perform an update in `Project.API`, the change does not seem to be present in `Prject.Service`, and vis versa.

I perform these updates using something like:

```
// get the object
MyObject myObj = _myDbContext.MyObject.Where( o => o.Id == 1 ).FirstOrDefault();

// Update some field on the object
myObj.IsActive = false;
_myDbContext.MyObject.Update( myObj );
_myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If I perform this update in `Project.API`, I can see the database has been updated, and if I try to perform the update for a second time, I can see that `myObj.IsActive` has been updated accordingly when viewing in Visual Studio inspector. However when the other assembly goes to make a change, it does not know about the update that has just been performed.

I must be missing something - how can I reflect changes made to `MyDbContext` in all assemblies that use it?

Comment: We raelly have to guess here. But maybe you referenced the debug version in some of them, but the release in the others and only updated one of the two?

Comment: how are the contexts instantiated, and how and when do they gather the object from the database?

Comment: @Christopher I'm not sure what you mean - the debug/release version of what; the assemblies? I reference the project rather than the assembly (the projects are all in the same solution), and I'm not sure how I would ference either the debug or release version.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro The context are injected on startup. I'm not sure how/when they gather the data from the database. I expected this would happen when I use the context to get the data (`MyObject myObj = _myDbContext.MyObject.Where( o => o.Id == 1 ).FirstOrDefault();`), but perhaps this is a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: it is, unless the object is already part of the context. Notice that ambient DbContexts are bound to become stale until they are reinstantiated.